# Count Datatable rows with specific String

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

How to count datatable rows with specific text?
I try to use filter() but is not working.

```
$("#buttonAlert").on("click", function (event) {

  var count = $("#example1").DataTable.rows
    .column(4)
    .data()
    .filter(function (value, index) {
      return value = "OK" ? true : false;
    }).length;

  alert('Total OK is: ' + count);

});
```

The error like below:

```
ssar:391 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'column' of undefined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (ssar:391)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:3)
    at HTMLButtonElement.r.handle (jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below one, I am pushing the rows to `matchedRows` array based on the column value equality...

```
  var matchedRows = [];
  var table = $('#table_id').DataTable();
  var data = table.data().toArray();
  data.forEach(function(row) {
    row.forEach(function (column) {
      if (column == "Row 1 Data 1") {
        matchedRows.push(row);
      }
    })
  });
  console.log(matchedRows.length);
```

Comment: I've checked in the respective codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EppebR?editors=1111

Comment: Hi, thank you, but I don't understand, I think this can be more simple

Comment: @BayuSriHernogo Sorry, I didn't get you. Is that solution working for you?

Comment: Hi, thanks you this work, but this still not standard Datatable function I think, but thank you I can use this method

Comment: @BayuSriHernogo yeah that's correct :-). But I used `Datatables` long back ago. I've to check the documentation once, if I find anything minimized code, I'll update my answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to use and `columns()` with `eq(4)` method of `dataTable` like

```
var count = 0;
$("#example1").DataTable.columns().eq(4).each( function ( index ) {
    var column = $("#example1").DataTable.column( index );
    var value = column.data();
    if(value === 'OK'){
      count++;
    }
});

console.log('length'+count);
```

Comment: Hi, Mr. Ankit, I try but still getting error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'each' of null